# AAM only working on half of links

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I am using SharePoint 2013 using IIS ARR as a reverse proxy.

I have set up an Alternative Access Mapping so that the site is reachable on 'portal.domain.com'.  When I set up port forwarding directly to SharePoint, everything works as expected.

However, when I forward the port to my reverse proxy server (which then directs the traffic to the sharepoint server), the page loads correctly at first but then the links on the top of the page (Newsfeed, SkyDrive and Sites) are all linking to the Default website (which is a local address).  All of the links in the body are written correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: These links may come from you mysite web application (if you have a separate web application for your mysite host and sites?). If so you should add AAM on this web application as well.

Comment: It is a default installation - I only have two applications 1) SharePoint and 2) SharePoint Central Administration v4.  I have set up Alternative Access Mappings on both to point to portal.domain.com